# Use polygon area to calculate the population density in R

Tags: r, area, rgdal, choropleth

I'm very new to R and I'm trying to make a density choropleth map. I want to calculate the population density of a administrative boundary in R using `rgal`:

```
path <- "recintos_municipales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp"
lineas_limite <- readOGR(path, use_iconv=TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I see how `rgal` creates a data structure where I can access easily to the `shapefile` attributes table by `lineas_limite@data` and to the polygons by `lineas_limite@polygons`.

I have a field in `lineas_limite@data` named `population` which I want to use against something as the native variables available in QGIS like `$area`.

Then I'd like to create a new `density` variable to represent it in a choropleth map:

```
coast@data <- coast@data %>%
  mutate(
      dens = population / area
  )
```

Is this the best way to make it?

The data comes from the Spanish National Geographic Institute ([link](http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/locale?request_locale=en) to the source).

The dataset name is **Municipal boundary lines**. The platform will download several files and the one I'm working with is `recintos_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89`.

On the other hand, I've created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/LuisSevillano/lineas-limite) with the shapefiles but those already have an area field which is the one I'm interesting in and which I created with QGIS (so don't pay attention because I'm trying to generate it from R).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

To calculate each polygon's area, you'll need to do two things:

1. Store each polygon's boundaries (seen here as a list of 77 matrices)
2. Calculate and store each polygon's area using the [`geosphere::areaPolygon()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/areaPolygon) function.

From there, you can proceed to calculate each polygon's population density.

---

## Reproducible Example

Here is an example that calculates the area for each of the [City of Chicago's 77 community areas](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6) (i.e. neighborhoods).

```
# install necessary packages
install.packages( pkgs = c( "geosphere", "sp", "rgdal" ) )

# load necessary packages
library( geosphere )
library( sp )
library( rgdal )

# store Chicago current community area
# GeoJSON URL as a character vector
geojson_comarea_url <- "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/geospatial/cauq-8yn6?method=export&format=GeoJSON"

# transform URL character vector into spatial dataframe
comarea606 <- readOGR( dsn = geojson_comarea_url
                       , layer = "OGRGeoJSON"
                       , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                       , verbose = FALSE # to hide progress message after object is created
)

## WRONG WAY is trusting the area slot within each polygon
wrong.list.of.polygon.areas <-
  data.frame(
    comarea606_Name           = comarea606$community
    , comarea606_Inherit_Area = sapply( X = slot( object = comarea606, name = "polygons" )
                                , FUN = function(i) 
                                  i@area )
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# view the wrong results
wrong.list.of.polygon.areas
#           comarea606_Name comarea606_Inherit_Area
# 1                 DOUGLAS            0.0004632396
# 2                 OAKLAND            0.0001702833
# 3             FULLER PARK            0.0002004699
# 4         GRAND BOULEVARD            0.0004881245
# 5                 KENWOOD            0.0002926158
# 6          LINCOLN SQUARE            0.0007200422
# 7         WASHINGTON PARK            0.0004263996
# 8               HYDE PARK            0.0004538953
# 9                WOODLAWN            0.0005816583
# 10            ROGERS PARK            0.0005175561
# 11         JEFFERSON PARK            0.0006546563
# 12            FOREST GLEN            0.0008997264
# 13             NORTH PARK            0.0007094071
# 14            ALBANY PARK            0.0005402586
# 15           PORTAGE PARK            0.0011116825
# 16            IRVING PARK            0.0009040059
# 17                DUNNING            0.0010449760
# 18              MONTCLARE            0.0002780923
# 19         BELMONT CRAGIN            0.0011001642
# 20             WEST RIDGE            0.0009936912
# 21                HERMOSA            0.0003287441
# 22               AVONDALE            0.0005576454
# 23           LOGAN SQUARE            0.0010089020
# 24          HUMBOLDT PARK            0.0010128203
# 25              WEST TOWN            0.0012858100
# 26                 AUSTIN            0.0020082609
# 27     WEST GARFIELD PARK            0.0003636864
# 28     EAST GARFIELD PARK            0.0005429495
# 29         NEAR WEST SIDE            0.0015968996
# 30         NORTH LAWNDALE            0.0009014540
# 31                 UPTOWN            0.0006568040
# 32         SOUTH LAWNDALE            0.0012889745
# 33        LOWER WEST SIDE            0.0008213691
# 34        NEAR SOUTH SIDE            0.0005013217
# 35          ARMOUR SQUARE            0.0002796204
# 36           NORWOOD PARK            0.0012862114
# 37        NEAR NORTH SIDE            0.0007728518
# 38                   LOOP            0.0004668873
# 39            SOUTH SHORE            0.0008228658
# 40                CHATHAM            0.0008277123
# 41            AVALON PARK            0.0003504538
# 42          SOUTH CHICAGO            0.0009378263
# 43               BURNSIDE            0.0001708577
# 44        CALUMET HEIGHTS            0.0004908500
# 45               ROSELAND            0.0013497948
# 46           NORTH CENTER            0.0005755101
# 47                PULLMAN            0.0005929323
# 48          SOUTH DEERING            0.0030522425
# 49              EAST SIDE            0.0008365337
# 50           WEST PULLMAN            0.0009980793
# 51              RIVERDALE            0.0009880640
# 52              HEGEWISCH            0.0014658303
# 53         GARFIELD RIDGE            0.0011864234
# 54         ARCHER HEIGHTS            0.0005629105
# 55          BRIGHTON PARK            0.0007640013
# 56          MCKINLEY PARK            0.0003970284
# 57              LAKE VIEW            0.0008796889
# 58             BRIDGEPORT            0.0005869749
# 59               NEW CITY            0.0013551840
# 60            WEST ELSDON            0.0003291759
# 61              GAGE PARK            0.0006167374
# 62               CLEARING            0.0007157968
# 63              WEST LAWN            0.0008280548
# 64           CHICAGO LAWN            0.0009886720
# 65         WEST ENGLEWOOD            0.0008847861
# 66              ENGLEWOOD            0.0008617058
# 67 GREATER GRAND CROSSING            0.0009942937
# 68           LINCOLN PARK            0.0008905024
# 69                ASHBURN            0.0013621619
# 70         AUBURN GRESHAM            0.0010564790
# 71                BEVERLY            0.0008922944
# 72     WASHINGTON HEIGHTS            0.0008004438
# 73        MOUNT GREENWOOD            0.0007594687
# 74            MORGAN PARK            0.0009230990
# 75                  OHARE            0.0037524990
# 76              EDGEWATER            0.0004890111
# 77            EDISON PARK            0.0003194218


## RIGHT WAY is calculating the area yourself

# store each polygon's boundaries
list.of.polygon.boundaries <- sapply( X = slot( object = comarea606, name = "polygons" )
                                 , FUN = function(i) 
                                   sp::coordinates( obj = slot( object = i, name = "Polygons")[[1]] )
)

# calculate each polygon's area in square meters
comarea606@data$Square_Meter_Area <- sapply( X = list.of.polygon.boundaries, FUN = geosphere::areaPolygon )

# view the right results
comarea606@data[ c( "community", "Square_Meter_Area" ) ]
#                community            Square_Meter_Area
# 1                 DOUGLAS                      4273829
# 2                 OAKLAND                      1571301
# 3             FULLER PARK                      1850268
# 4         GRAND BOULEVARD                      4504952
# 5                 KENWOOD                      2700750
# 6          LINCOLN SQUARE                      6628739
# 7         WASHINGTON PARK                      3936533
# 8               HYDE PARK                      4190262
# 9                WOODLAWN                      5370998
# 10            ROGERS PARK                      4762104
# 11         JEFFERSON PARK                      6026453
# 12            FOREST GLEN                      8280516
# 13             NORTH PARK                      6529977
# 14            ALBANY PARK                      4974190
# 15           PORTAGE PARK                     10237543
# 16            IRVING PARK                      8325095
# 17                DUNNING                      9624357
# 18              MONTCLARE                      2561945
# 19         BELMONT CRAGIN                     10135661
# 20             WEST RIDGE                      9144227
# 21                HERMOSA                      3028810
# 22               AVONDALE                      5136605
# 23           LOGAN SQUARE                      9295521
# 24          HUMBOLDT PARK                      9334890
# 25              WEST TOWN                     11850755
# 26                 AUSTIN                     18511300
# 27     WEST GARFIELD PARK                      3353110
# 28     EAST GARFIELD PARK                      5005851
# 29         NEAR WEST SIDE                     14724107
# 30         NORTH LAWNDALE                      8313567
# 31                 UPTOWN                      6047440
# 32         SOUTH LAWNDALE                     11891299
# 33        LOWER WEST SIDE                      7576149
# 34        NEAR SOUTH SIDE                      4623602
# 35          ARMOUR SQUARE                      2579489
# 36           NORWOOD PARK                     11839116
# 37        NEAR NORTH SIDE                      7123217
# 38                   LOOP                      4304581
# 39            SOUTH SHORE                      7600312
# 40                CHATHAM                      7647583
# 41            AVALON PARK                      3237793
# 42          SOUTH CHICAGO                      8664835
# 43               BURNSIDE                      1578918
# 44        CALUMET HEIGHTS                      4535904
# 45               ROSELAND                     12477753
# 46           NORTH CENTER                      5300414
# 47                PULLMAN                      5481215
# 48          SOUTH DEERING                     28222390
# 49              EAST SIDE                      7732987
# 50           WEST PULLMAN                      9231061
# 51              RIVERDALE                      9140344
# 52              HEGEWISCH                     13559960
# 53         GARFIELD RIDGE                     10952400
# 54         ARCHER HEIGHTS                      5195326
# 55          BRIGHTON PARK                      7050570
# 56          MCKINLEY PARK                      3663260
# 57              LAKE VIEW                      8102329
# 58             BRIDGEPORT                      5415321
# 59               NEW CITY                     12507893
# 60            WEST ELSDON                      3038932
# 61              GAGE PARK                      5693468
# 62               CLEARING                      6609603
# 63              WEST LAWN                      7647276
# 64           CHICAGO LAWN                      9130323
# 65         WEST ENGLEWOOD                      8170431
# 66              ENGLEWOOD                      7957145
# 67 GREATER GRAND CROSSING                      9183452
# 68           LINCOLN PARK                      8204655
# 69                ASHBURN                     12584519
# 70         AUBURN GRESHAM                      9760656
# 71                BEVERLY                      8247709
# 72     WASHINGTON HEIGHTS                      7398212
# 73        MOUNT GREENWOOD                      7021929
# 74            MORGAN PARK                      8535503
# 75                  OHARE                     34379638
# 76              EDGEWATER                      4501053
# 77            EDISON PARK                      2939134

# end of script #
```

### Mistrusting the Inherit 'area' Slot Within Each Polygon

According to the documentation for [`?sp::Polygons-class`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-7/topics/Polygon-class), the `area` slot within each polygon is not the actual area.

> Object of class "numeric"; the gross total planar area of the Polygon list but not double-counting holes (changed from 0.9-58 - islands are summed, holes are ignored rather than subtracted); these values are used to make sure that polygons of a smaller area are plotted after polygons of a larger area, does not respect projection as objects of this class have no projection defined.

It seems more like a placeholder than the actual value you are seeking, which is why I used the [`geosphere::areaPolygon()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/areaPolygon) function to obtain that value.

---

## Update

The OP's data was made available via a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/LuisSevillano/lineas-limite). Down below is the same logic from above, only using different data.

```
# install necessary packages
install.packages( pkgs = c( "geosphere", "sp", "rgdal" ) )

# load necessary packages
library( geosphere )
library( sp )
library( rgdal )

# load necessary data

# download a .zip file of the GitHub repository
download.file( url = "https://github.com/LuisSevillano/lineas-limite/archive/master.zip"
                                     , destfile = "lineas-limite-master.zip"
) #39.2MB ~ 1 minute DL time on my crappy wifi

# unzip the entire GitHub repository
unzip( zipfile = "lineas-limite-master.zip" )

# set working directory to be
# inside the sub-folder where
# the shapefiles of interest are located
setwd( dir = "/Users/cristiannuno/Downloads/lineas-limite-master/recintos_municipales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89/" )

# create spatial polygon data frame
lineas_limite <- rgdal::readOGR( dsn = getwd()
                                 , layer = "recintos_municipales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89"
                                 , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                                 )


# store each polygon's boundaries
list.of.polygon.boundaries <- sapply( X = slot( object = lineas_limite, name = "polygons" )
                                      , FUN = function(i) 
                                        sp::coordinates( obj = slot( object = i, name = "Polygons")[[1]] )
)

# calculate each polygon's area in square meters
lineas_limite@data$Square_Meter_Area <- sapply( X = list.of.polygon.boundaries
                                             , FUN = geosphere::areaPolygon 
)

# View the first six results
head(
  lineas_limite@data[ c( "NAMEUNIT", "Square_Meter_Area" ) ]
)

#    NAMEUNIT Square_Meter_Area
# 0      Abla          45244459
# 1  Abrucena          83677254
# 2      Adra          89694443
# 3 Albánchez          35133840
# 4 Alboloduy          69734542
# 5  Pradejón          31755520

# end of script #
```

---

## Resources

I encourage you to read through the [`?sp::Polygons-class`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-7/topics/Polygon-class) documentation, as well as the [SpatialPointsDataFrame properties and operators in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/spatialpointsdataframe-properties-and-operators-in-r) to learn more about spatial polygons and how to use them in R.

---

## Session Info

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.2-16    geosphere_1.5-7 sp_1.2-7       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15       lattice_0.20-35    digest_0.6.14      mime_0.5          
 [5] grid_3.4.3         R6_2.2.2           xtable_1.8-2       magrittr_1.5      
 [9] leaflet_1.1.0.9000 tools_3.4.3        htmlwidgets_1.0    crosstalk_1.0.0   
[13] shiny_1.0.5        httpuv_1.3.5       yaml_2.1.16        compiler_3.4.3    
[17] htmltools_0.3.6
```

---

## RStudio Version

```
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio,
  Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.1.419’
```

Comment: @LuisSP, no problem! If my post answered your question, feel free to up vote and mark the post as answered.

Comment: thanks @aspiringurbandatascientist, but I'm still in trouble. I create `list.of.polygon.boundaries`: 
`> str(list.of.polygon.boundaries)
List of 542
 $ : num [1:118, 1:2] 222648 222683 222702 222703 222560 ...
 $ : num [1:344, 1:2] 176601 178198 178803 179018 179460 ...`
But `lineas_limite@data$Square_Meter_Area` results NaN: 
`> str(lineas_limite@data[ c( "NAMEUNIT", "Square_Meter_Area" ) ])
'data.frame': 542 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ NAMEUNIT         : chr  "l'Atzúbia" "Agost" "Agres" "Aigües" ...
 $ Square_Meter_Area: num  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...`

Comment: @LuisSP, unfortunately, without a reproducible example, I can't diagnose what's going on that is leading your `Square_Meter_Area` to result in a vector of [`NaN`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.finite.html) values. 

Any chance you can update your question with a download of your spatial polygon data frame?

Comment: I've edited the question to add a couple of links to the spatial polygons. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisSP, updated my answer by replacing my example data with your data. I was able to successfully calculate the area for each polygon with no trouble. Let me know where the disconnect is after seeing my updated code from up above.

Comment: Thank you very much @aspiringurbandatascientist!

Comment: No problem @LuisSP! Good luck with the rest of your project.